# OpenWhisk can`t import module

Tags: ipython, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I am using OpenWhisk on Bluemix . I need to make the following in order to redirect std streams:

```
from IPython.utils.io import capture_output
```

I encounter an error

```
ImportError: No module named IPython.utils.io
```

Is there a solution there for missing modules?

Comment: This is usually solved by uploading a zip file containing the action + dependencies. According to https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/1505 it doesn't seem to be solved just yet.

Comment: @markusthoemmes Does it depend on Python version which OpenWgisk suppot on Bluemix? I.e. switching to 3.x could solve missing modules issue?